# What method is called when using dot notation in MyClass.my_attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print "getting x attr" whenever I use the dot notation to get an attribute.

For example

```py
class MyClass:
   my_attribute = "abc"

print(MyClass.my_attribute)
```

I'd expect it to output like this:

```
>>> getting my_attribute attr
>>> abc
```

I'm *not* instantiating the class.
I tried to add a print statement to `MyClass.__getattr__()` and `MyClass.__getattribute__()` but none of these will display anything.

I tried the following:

```
class MyClass:
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print("running __getattr__")
        return super().__getattr__(key)
    
    def __getattribute__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        print("running __getattribute__")
        return super().__getattribute__(__name)

    my_attribute = "abc"
```

Comment: Also, be aware you're using the class, not an instance. Perhaps that's intentional, but it will make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyClass` (the class object) is itself an object. You want to define your custom [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method on the class that `MyClass` is an instance of. To do that, use a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/11082165):

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print(f"getting {item}")
        return super().__getattribute__(item)


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    my_class_attribute = "abc"
```

then

```
print(type(MyClass))
print(MyClass.my_class_attribute)
```

outputs

```
<class '__main__.MyMeta'>
getting my_class_attribute
abc
```